# Can I use the P3020L Mosfet with 5>Vgs>3 without any linear region consequences?

Tags: voltage, mosfet, nmos, gate-driving, powermosfet

So I've been searching for a long time, for a power mosfet I can switch safely at a Vgs of 3V. I'd like to know if this is the one, because luckily, I recovered it from a computer power supply, thus I actually have it.

[Link to the datasheet](https://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/24368/STMICROELECTRONICS/STP3020L.html)

So the minimum Vth is 1V and the maximum is 2.5V, hence 3V is going to switch it fully on right?

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as a transistor "fully on".

There is "acceptably low resistance between the source and the drain (Rds)" and/or "staying safely away from the saturation region".

In the datasheet you attached, you may want to look at the "Output characteristics" graph. You will see that at 3V gate voltage, the transistor more or less behaves if the drain current is limited below 6A.

If you want to switch higher currents, you will need higher voltages at the drain in order to keep the transistor out of saturation.

p.s. "Behaves" for a switching transistor is that Rds stays mostly linear and low enough that Vds stays below 1V.

Depending on your project, you may or may not want higher criteria for a "fully on" transistor.

Answer (score 0):

From the [STP3020L datasheet](http://pdf.datasheetcatalog.com/datasheet/SGSThomsonMicroelectronics/mXtysvr.pdf%27): -

[image]

So, if the current is low (say 6 amps) then the volt drop between drain and source will be about 0.5 volts. That's an equivalent resistance of around 83 mΩ (milliohms).

> *hence 3V is going to switch it fully on right?*

Well, it depends what you mean by fully on. If you mean a short circuit then no, because 83 mΩ is certainly not 0 mΩ. But, what if the current is around 9 amps. The volt drop will be about 6 volts and, that's an equivalent resistance of 667 mΩ and nothing like a short circuit. In fact you could make an argument that with 9 amps forced through the device, the volt drop is anything between 6 volts and 16 volts (the graph permits us to only see 16 volts on the x-axis) hence, it certainly is not fully-on and will likely burn and smoke if you tried this.

If you applied a 5 volt drive level to the gate with respect to the source then it's a much better picture.

Answer (score 0):

> So the minimum Vth is 1V and the maximum is 2.5V, hence 3V is going to
> switch it fully on right?

You are describing the Gate Threshold Voltage, which has a range of possible voltages required to turn the FET on *just enough* to pass a current of 250 μA (with V<sub>DS</sub> = V<sub>GS</sub>). Why a range rather than a single value? Due to manufacturing process variations the threshold voltage of individual FETs varies widely. Your FET will have a threshold voltage *somewhere* within that range, but you won't know where until you test it.

The datasheet shows the output characteristics for a *typical* unit, which is 'fully on' with 3 V at up to ~6 amps. If you are lucky your FET's threshold voltage is towards the lower end of the range, so it will be turned on at least as well as the datasheet shows with 3 V. But if you are unlucky and the threshold voltage is towards the top end of the range it won't be.

So just try it. If it can switch enough current for your application with 3 V on the Gate then it's good enough for you.

But the next one you get might not be good enough, so if you are designing a circuit for *production* you should either specify a FET which is *designed* for a Gate drive voltage of 3 V or lower (and so is guaranteed to turn on 'fully' with 3 V), or provide more Gate voltage by eg. using a level shifter circuit or Gate driver IC.